# Transferi uma image de uma imageview para outra imageview em outra fragment

Tags: java, android

Galera tenho uma grid view que exibe imagens de um servidor, quando se clika na imagem eu tenho que recarregar a imagem de novo mais alguns detalhes, eu queria que invés de ter que baixar a imagem de novo, ou seja eu queria passar a imagem da imageview já carregada para outra imageview.
A GridView

```
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                //String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();

                String pid = productsList.get(position).getPid();

                  ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
                  Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                        DetailFragment f = new DetailFragment();
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();

                        args.putParcelable("SEU_BITMAP", bitmap);

                        f.setArguments(args);

                boolean singlepane = MainActivity.getPane();
                if(singlepane== true){
                    /*
                     * The second fragment not yet loaded. 
                     * Load DetailFragment by FragmentTransaction, and pass 
                     * data from current fragment to second fragment via bundle.
                     */



                    DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
                    Fragment myListFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ListFragment");

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("TAG_PID",pid);
                    detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                            getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(
                            R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout, R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

                    //This could use some improvement, but it works, hide current fragment, show new one
                    fragmentTransaction.hide(myListFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.phone_container, detailFragment);
                    //fragmentTransaction.show(myDetailFragment);


                    /*
                     * Add this transaction to the back stack. 
                     * This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is 
                     * committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off 
                     * the stack.
                     */
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

A Segunda fragment

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    //creating the variables
                                    String description;
                                    String name;
                                    String tags;
                                    String downloads;
                                    String created;
                                    try {
                                        //filling the variables with json content
                                        url = (product.getString(TAG_URL));
                                        //description = (product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
                                        name = (product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                                        tags = (product.getString(TAG_TAGS));
                                        downloads = (product.getString(TAG_DOWNLOADS));
                                        created = (product.getString(TAG_CREATED));

                                        // Getting the tags in a gridview
                                        stringArray = tags.split(",");

                                        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++)
                                            stringArray[i] = stringArray[i].trim();


                                        mylistview = (ExpandableHeightGridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewTags);

                                        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                                R.layout.tag_gridview_item, R.id.tagbutton,
                                                stringArray);
                                        mylistview.setAdapter(listAdapter);                                   
                                        Bitmap bitmap = getArguments().getParcelable("SEU_BITMAP");

                                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode recuperar o `Bitmap` da `ImageView` e passar por argumento via `Arguments` da classe `Fragment`. A classe `Bitmap` implementa a interface `Parcelable`, logo é possível passa-lá para um `Bundle`.

Para recuperar o `Bitmap` de uma `ImageView` basta usar:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Para passar via Intent para um outro `Fragment`:

```
SeuFragment f = new SeuFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();

args.putParcelable("SEU_BITMAP", bitmap);

f.setArguments(args);
```

Para recuperar no `SeuFragment`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = getArguments().getParcelable("SEU_BITMAP");
```

E para setar o `Bitmap` ao seu `ImageView`:

```
ImageView imageView = ...;

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Acontece isso The method putExtra(String, Bitmap) is undefined for the type Bundle

Comment: Engano meu, o método correto é `putParcelable`, corrigido na resposta.

Comment: Ta passando uma image nula, não exibe nada.

Comment: Poderia incluir na pergunta como ficou o código?

Comment: Coloquei uma parte.

Comment: @AlissonHirle, pelo que vi do código você instancia o `DetailFragment` duas vezes, uma com a variável `f`, que possui o Bitmap e outra com a variável `detailFragment` que não tem o `Bitmap` e ai acaba apenas usando o `detailFragment` para fazer o `replace`.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.